# Strange behaviour when adding and animating imageViews in android

Tags: android, animation, imageview, pivot, center

I've got a LinearLayout with a background bitmap. I'm adding 2-3 images to this layout with an animation. The problem is: everytime im adding images the FIRST image animation starts from the top left corner, for every other image directly after that animation it works just fine from the center. Im struggling for days to find a solution for this little annoying problem. Do u have any advise what could cause this?

Here my problem in a gif I made: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNsqY.jpg

my animation:`

```
<scale
    android:duration="750"
    android:fillAfter="false"
    android:fromXScale="0"
    android:fromYScale="0.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0" />
```

`

my layout:

```
<LinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/layoutCompareUppoints"
   android:layout_width="140dp"
   android:layout_height="28dp"
   android:background="@drawable/uppballsbgnew" >
</LinearLayout>
```

my code: 
`private void animUppointsBefore() {

```
    if (k < Integer.valueOf(uppoints)) {

        Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                R.anim.debug_grow_fast_animation);


    ImageView upp = new ImageView(this);
    upp.setImageResource(R.drawable.uppballlightnew);
    upp.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    uppLayout.addView(upp);
    upp.startAnimation(a);
    a.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation a) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation a) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation a) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            k++;
            animUppointsBefore();

        }
    });

    }

}`
```

Comment: it will help if you add the code in your Q

Comment: I added my animation code. But I want to say again that my code is working fine for every image after I added the first one. That makes it so hard to understand

Comment: Have you tried RelativeLayout? I know LinearLayout is not quite friendly with free image operations

Comment: Not yet, I want my images to be shown next to the previous added one, thats why is used linear layout

Comment: Same behaviour with relativeLayout :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're most likely seeing is the image is getting added to the layout before any animation actually takes place. The image is going to start full size, shrink down to 0, then grow up to 1.

What you want to do is make it invisible before you add it then make it appear off screen.  A couple of methods you can do, the usual way is to set the `ImageView` to `View#INVISIBLE` then with an `Animation#AnimationListener`, set the view to `View#VISIBLE` on animation start.

If you can, using [Animators](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/Animator.html) are way easier (There are some libraries in the support library that don't allow this).  You can set the View's Alpha to 0 before adding it, then just set it to 1 instantly as part of the animation.  Just make two `ObjectAnimators`, one for alpha and one for scale, then combine them in to a single `AnimatorSet`.

EDIT:

To put the final answer from comments to here.

Rather than adding the views just before animating, it may help to put the image views already laid out in the layout but invisible.  That way, there doesn't need to be a new layout and measure pass that could be screwing up the measurements to the pivot point.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed Answer! Unfortunately this does not help me to solve the problem. I made a gif of what excatly is going on in my animation. I would be very thankful if u take your time to look at it. 
http://imgur.com/FCPgof1

Comment: Oh, that's interesting.  It looks like the pivot point is on the 0%,0% corner. I'm not sure what would cause that at the top of my head, but one thing you can try is to keep the images all laid out but invisible. That way they overall layout is always there and there's no need to remeasure (which would occur when you add views).  Actually now that I think about it, the pivot may be calculated to 0,0 because at this time the ImageViews don't have a width or height.

Comment: Yes that would probably be a working solution to my problem although its a bit frustrating to rewrite the code which is basically working except for  that stupid first image :D But many thanks that you took your time, I think im gonna try it the way u proposed.

Comment: Thanks man its finally working!! Although I dont have an explanation for my issue its probably better to just do it in a simplier way.